# How do I install Terraform libvrit_cloudinit?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I have searched all day trying to find a document on how to install the `libvirt_cloudinit` provider for Terraform.

When I execute a `terraform plan` I encounter this error message:

```
Error: libvirt_cloudinit.commoninit: Provider doesn't support resource: libvirt_cloudinit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use libvirt_cloudinit_disk instead of libvirt_cloudinit. I think it is deprecated.